# Don't know what's wrong with my code. Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, jcomponent

I'm trying to make a combo box that pops up with an image. I get this error:

> Note: C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\TUSEG\Program\ProductDemo.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Anyway, when it tries to pull up a picture, I get this every time:

> Couldn't find file: C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\TUSEG\Program\images\microsoft\Xbox 360 Controller (PC).jpg
>   Couldn't find file: C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\TUSEG\Program\images\microsoft\Wireless Laser Mouse 5000.jpg

The path is most definitely correct. I'm not sure what my problem is. If anyone could take a look at this and help me?

```
    package components;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class ProductDemo extends JPanel
                      implements ActionListener {
JLabel picture;

public ProductDemo() {
    super(new BorderLayout());

    String pMS[] = new String[23];
    pMS[0] = ("LifeChat LX-3000");
    pMS[1] = ("LifeChat ZX-6000");
    pMS[2] = ("Wireless Notebook Presenter 8000");
    pMS[3] = ("Arc Mouse");
    pMS[4] = ("Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000");
    pMS[5] = ("Explorer Mouse");
    pMS[6] = ("Explorer Mini Mouse");
    pMS[7] = ("Sidewinder X8 Mouse");
    pMS[8] = ("Wireless Laser Mouse 5000");
    pMS[9] = ("Wireless Mobile Mouse 3000");
    pMS[10] = ("Wireless Mobile Mouse 6000");
    pMS[11] = ("Arc Keyboard");
    pMS[12] = ("Bluetooth Mobile Keyboard 6000");
    pMS[13] = ("Sidewinder X4 Keyboard");
    pMS[14] = ("Sidewinder X6 Keyboard");
    pMS[15] = ("Ergonomic Desktop 7000");
    pMS[16] = ("Wireless Desktop 3000");
    pMS[17] = ("Wireless Laser Desktop 6000 v2.0");
    pMS[18] = ("Wireless Media Desktop 1000");
    pMS[19] = ("Windows Server 2008 Enterprise");
    pMS[20] = ("Notebook Cooling Base");
    pMS[21] = ("Xbox 360 Controller (PC)");
    pMS[22] = ("Xbox 360 Controller");
    Arrays.sort(pMS);

    //Indices start at 0, so 4 specifies the last index of the product.
    JComboBox msList = new JComboBox(pMS);
    msList.setSelectedIndex(22);
    msList.addActionListener(this);

    //Set up the picture.
    picture = new JLabel();
    picture.setFont(picture.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));
    picture.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    updateLabel(pMS[msList.getSelectedIndex()]);
    picture.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,0,0,0));

    //height + width
    picture.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

    //Lays out the demo.
    add(msList, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(picture, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
}

/** Listens to the combo box. */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    String pMS = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
    updateLabel(pMS);
}

protected void updateLabel(String name) {
    ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Desktop\\TUSEG\\Program\\images\\microsoft\\" + name + ".jpg");
    picture.setIcon(icon);
    if (icon != null) {
        picture.setText(null);
    }
    else {
        picture.setText("Image not found");
    }
}

/** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = ProductDemo.class.getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ProductDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    JComponent newContentPane = new ProductDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: `uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.` I don't get that warning when compiling the code using a Java 6 SDK.  1) What version are you using?  2) What extra output is obtained when `-Xlint:unchecked` is added to the compilation options?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't know how to run that (-Xlint:unchecked), and I'm using Java 6 SDK too... I'm kind of noobish at coding.

Comment: @KyleLawson : JAR FILE CREATION : say your project's directory structure is like(C:\Project), which contains subdirectories as classes and src and your manifest.txt file (Main-Class:<space>components.ProductDemo<After this do Press your Enter Key and save the file>). So since you are creating a package, so from your command prompt, go to your classes folder i.e. C:\Project\classes, now type jar -cfm anyNameYouWantToGiveToTheFile.jar ..\manifest.txt components<Press Enter>. This will create your jar file. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing a `File` based path like..

```
C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\TUSEG\Program\images\microsoft\Xbox 360 Controller (PC).jpg
```

..with a relative reference for use in `getResource(String)`, such as:

```
"images/microsoft/Xbox 360 Controller (PC).jpg"
```

The `getResource()` method expects a string using forward slashes, that is relative to the run-time class-path of the application (so the `images` directory etc. would most usually be added to a Jar).  To ensure it works from a class from any package, prefix the string with `/`.

```
"/images/microsoft/Xbox 360 Controller (PC).jpg"
```

The `getResource()` method will return an `URL`, so be sure to use URL compatible constructors.

Comment: Well, can you perhaps link me to how to make it into a .jar? I wanted to do that as well, but I can't find any information relevant. What additional stuff would I need to do? I know i need my manifest with my main class, but other than that how do I do it?!

Answer (score 1):

Decide if you want to load the images from the file system, or from the classpath of the application.

If from the file system, use file IO to load the icon, or the constructor taking a file name as argument:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("c:\\....jpg");
```

If from the classpath, then the path is a / separated path starting from the root of the classpath, and the images should be stored in the same directory/jar as your classes (or in another directory/jar that is in the classpath):

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ProductDemo.class.getResource("/path/to/image.jpg"));
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29